# Can i call a java script function to redirect to a particular view if browser refresh button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

If at any point of time the user clicks on refresh icon on the browser, I want to redirect the user to a view ("UploadFilesView").

Is it possible to achieve? if yes, any code example would make my day!

My code is in MVC, using JavaScript and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#btnRefreshIcon").click(function () {

 var url = '@Url.Action("UploadFilesView", "<ControllerName>")';

 var win = window.open(url, '_blank');  // _blank - To open view in next tab and 
                                        // _self - To open view in same tab
            win.focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate! but how do i detect "#btnRefreshIcon". It is the default refresh icon on the chrome browser. how will my code identify it as #btnRefreshIcon?

Comment: Make UploadFilesView as an default view  --- or else in the Index action method --Redirect it to UploadFilesView action method.